# connecting two tables by maximum value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple tables.
Table1 contains IIN of people (unique identification number). Table2 contains IINs and person_id's. Table3 contains table3_id, person_id's, addr_id, date_reg. Table4 contains addr_id and other columns. I need to retireve table1.iin, table3.date_reg, and all the columns that table4 has for each IIN in table1. The problem is that the relationship between table2 and table3 is one-to-many. So for each iin we have multiple table3_id's. I need to connect only to records with the maximum table3_id.
How can i do this?
i use oracle sql

thanks in advance

Table1:

| IIN |
| --- |
| 0101 |
| 0201 |
| 0301 |
| 0401 |

Table2:

| person_id | IIN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0101 |
| 2 | 0201 |
| 3 | 0301 |
| 4 | 0401 |

Table3:

| ID | person_id | id_addr | date_reg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 02.06.2022 |
| 2 | 2 | 23 | 06.03.2012 |
| 3 | 1 | 34 | 07.05.2015 |
| 4 | 3 | 45 | 30.05.2020 |
| 5 | 3 | 56 | 06.12.2022 |
| 6 | 3 | 67 | 07.10.2020 |

Table4:

| id | other attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 12 |  |
| 23 |  |
| 34 |  |
| 45 |  |
| 56 |  |
| 67 |  |

Result:

| IIN | date_reg | id_addr | other attributes from table 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0101 | 07.05.2015 | 34 |  |
| 0201 | 06.03.2012 | 23 |  |
| 0301 | 07.10.2020 | 67 |  |
| 0401 |  |  |  |

```
    select table1.iin, table4.rka, table4.street, table4.house,                                                         
    table3.date_reg from table1
    left join table2 on table2.iin=table1.iin
    left join table3 on table2.person_id=table3.person_id
    left join table4 on table3.id_addr=table4.id
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and improve your question as explained there

Comment: It looks like there is a 1:1 relation between IIN and person_id. Is this correct? Or can it happen that one IIN is given to more than one person_id? (In other words: Are IID and person_id both unique in table 2 or is just their combination unique?)

Comment: And why do you outer join table 2 to table 3? D you want to show unused IINs in your result?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, there is 1:1 relationship. It's a long story, but it needs to be that way. IIN and person_id are both unique. And yes, I would like to show unused IINs with blank attributes

Comment: I've added an answer. There should be many answers on this in stackoverflow already, which you'd find when looking for "top n rows" or the like. But I wanted to show you may favorite aproach. I suggest, though, you look up other answers to top-n requests, too, in order to learn from them and see all the other solutions available.

Comment: See that I've changed the request tags. I have added Oracle and removed the Oracle SQL Developer, because we are not interested in what tool you are using to query your database, but must know which DBMS you use. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS and ideally even with your DBMS version, e.g. `sql` `oracle` `oracle-19c`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply subquery within the main query you can achieve your result.

**SQL EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT
  t1.IIN,
  t3.date_reg,
  t3.id_addr,
  t4.other_attributes
FROM
  Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.IIN = t2.IIN
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      t3a.person_id,
      MAX(t3a.id) AS max_id
    FROM
      Table3 t3a
    GROUP BY t3a.person_id
  ) subq ON t2.person_id = subq.person_id
  JOIN Table3 t3 ON subq.person_id = t3.person_id AND subq.max_id = t3.id
  JOIN Table4 t4 ON t3.id_addr = t4.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. After all this is all about table 3 and getting its rows with the maximum date per person. So, you could for instance just use your existing query and add

```
and (table3.person_id , table3.date_reg) in
(
  select person_id, max(date_reg)
  from table3
  group by person_id
)
```

to the `ON` clause for table 3.

What I prefer though is a CTE (aka `WITH` clause) getting the top table 3 rows and working with them:

```
with top_table3 as
(
  select *
  from table3
  order by row_number() over (partition by person_id order by date_reg desc)
  fetch first row with ties
)
select t1.iin, t4.rka, t4.street, t4.house, t3.date_reg
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.iin = t1.iin
left join top_top_table3 t3 on t3.person_id = t2.person_id
left join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.id_addr
order by t1.iin;
```

Well, how does this CTE work? We number each row per person starting with #1 for its newest date, #2 for its penultimate date and so on. Then we order the rows by those numbers, getting ties with all those wanted rows numbered #1 first. Then we say we want the first row and all its ties, i.e. all the newest rows, one per person.